# Queries to check whether all the elements in the given range occurs even number of times

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array arr[] containing N integers and there are Q queries where each query consists of a range [L, R]. The task is to find whether all the elements from the given index range have even frequency or not.

Can Someone give better solution than `O(n * q)`.
Solution given on this link is incorrect.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queries-to-check-whether-all-the-elements-in-the-given-index-range-occur-even-number-of-times/

Example is below:

```
Input: arr[] = {100, 100, 200, 100}, Q[][] = {{1, 4}, {1, 2}}
Output:
No
Yes 

Input: arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1}, Q[][] = {{1, 5}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}} 
Output: 
No
Yes
Yes
```

Comment: From your link, there is another solution no ? Why posting this question

Comment: @Quade because it is wrong, example arr[] = {1,2,3} Q[][]= {{1,3}} answer is NO, but given algorithm in the URL outputs YES

Comment: Yeah you're right, it seems the way they use xor returns false positives. They didn't expect that 1 xor 2 xor 3 will equal 0

Comment: @Quade geeksforgeeks is always wrong, never trust them.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
You can replace each values (mapping) to big random values (32-bit as example) and use algorithm from your url. It will work with a sufficiently high probability.

**Solution 2 (without xor):**
Sort all queries by pair `(L_i / sqrt(n), R_i)`. Now when moving between query `(L_i, R_i)` to `(L_{i+1}, R_{i+1})` need to add/remove some elements. We do it element by element to support number of each value and count number different group size. Algorithm complexity is `O(Q * log Q + (N + Q) * sqrt N)`.

*Little explanation*: After sort total number operation of add/delete elements equal to sum `|L_i - L_{i + 1}| + |R_i - R_{i + 1}|`.
**Sum difference L**: If `L_i / sqrt(n) = L_{i + 1} / sqrt(n)` then `|L_i - L_{i + 1}| <= sqrt(n)` (no more than `Q * sqrt(n)` for all query).
If `L_i / sqrt(n) < L_{i + 1} / sqrt(n)` then we go to some next block `sqrt(n)` and total number operation for it no more than `O(n)` (because `L_i` is increasing).
**Sum difference R**: If `L_i / sqrt(n) = L_{i + 1} / sqrt(n)` then `R_i` is increasing and total sum `|R_i - R_{i + 1}|` no more than `O(n)`. Number different `sqrt(n)` blocks is `n / sqrt(n) = sqrt(n)`. Then total operation no more `O(n * sqrt(n))`.
If `L_i / sqrt(n) < L_{i + 1} / sqrt(n)` then `|R_i - R_{i + 1}|` is `O(n)`, but number of such cases is `n / sqrt(n) = sqrt(n)`. Total is `O(n * sqrt(n))`.

Comment: I could do that. but can you give solution which doen't use XOR operation?

Comment: @guptashekhar54 added without xor.

Comment: Can you explain your solution 2 little more by taking a example? When soritng why we divide `L_i` by `sqrt(n)`?

Comment: @guptashekhar54 added a bit of explanation.